# I return a dict from the views.py to the templates as a value of a radio, but it looks like the "value" would cut down the text

Tags: python, html, django, forms

This is a templates,test_words.html

```
<form action="" method="GET">        
    <input type="radio" name ="option" value={{pre_ques.option1}}> {{pre_ques.option1}}</label>
    <input type="radio" name ="option" value={{pre_ques.option2 }}> {{pre_ques.option2}}</label>
    <input type="radio" name ="option" value={{pre_ques.option3 }}>{{pre_ques.option3 }}</label>
    <input type="radio" name ="option" value={{pre_ques.option4 }}>{{pre_ques.option4 }}</label>
    <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" name="next" value="Show the next">
</form>
```

and It could show completely in

```
<label> {{pre_ques.option4 }}</label>
```

Bu, if I try to

```
 option_value = request.GET.get('option')
 return HttpResponse (option_value)
```

it just show a part of {{pre_ques.option4}},  show like  "a." or "n.".

But,it should be "n. 疏远,离间,割让"
What problem cause that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to put the value in quotes.

```
<input type="radio" name ="option" value="{{pre_ques.option1}}">
```